# Copying List Items between two lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I just have a small requirement where in i have a list A and i want to copy all the existing items from list a to another list b. 
Then, when a new item is created in list a it should also get created in list b.

How do i achieve all of this?

Thanks

Comment: How many existing items do you have in your list A? Have you already created list B and does this list too has existing items? And more important list B must have same fields as list A.

Comment: so i have not created list b but yes list b will have some similar columns as list A. List A has 1400 items.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that list B has same fields as list A to copy data from list A to list B.

**For copying Existing items**:

1. You can create list B using the list template of list A. While saving the list template make sure you checked the checkbox next to "Include Content".

Use following sources to save list template and create new list using list template:

- [Manage list templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393).
- [Create a list from an existing template](http://ffconfluence.cloudapp.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/7274503).

  2. You can also use PowerShell to copy list items from one list to another list.

Sources:

- [Copy List Items Between SharePoint Lists using Powershell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/10/copy-list-items-between-sharepoint-lists-using-powershell.html?m=1).
- [Copy List Items From One SharePoint List To Another Using CSOM Powershell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/copy-list-items-from-one-sharepoint-list-to-another-using-csom-powershell).

**To Copy newly created items**:

1. Using SharePoint Designer, create a new workflow (Workflow -> List workflow). Specify the list to attach the workflow to(list A).
2. Navigate to workflow setting and specify that the workflow should start on item creation only.
3. Add an action: Copy list item and specify the list to copy to(list B).

Comment: I tried creating a template but i got a error saying the list size is too big and template cannot be created. Now is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Strange. With only 1400 items it should create list template without any error.

Comment: it is saying the list template size is greater than 52 mb. if i do not include my content it is of no use.

Comment: You can use powershell to copy items. See updated answer.

Comment: where do i paste the power shell script?

Comment: Create the script in a plain text editor such as Notepad and save with a .PS1 file extension (for example, myscript.ps1) and to run this script use windows powershell or PowerShell ISE as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script).

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: No, i am not sure if my company allows me to use power shell. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Yes, but for that you need to code. Export list data into excel file and upload all the data from excel into new list using batch proccessing in jSOM

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a position to use Microsoft Flow to implement this ? You can create a flow on Manual trigger that gets all item from List A and creates the items in List B in a loop. This will be one time

You can have a second flow on "When a list item is created" trigger on List A. Everytime an item is created, you can create an item in list B

Comment: i do not have access to flows. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: to gain access for flow browse to https://flow.microsoft.com and sign in with your userid and password